# What is the meaning of the following expression in xPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

Can someone help me to understand how to read the following expression in xpath? what is the meaning of this expression?
`//*/id(@*)/*`

Answer (score 0):

It's a strange and cryptic expression, but I'll try to decipher it.

The initial `//` is an abbreviation for `/descendant-or-self::node()/` and `*` refers to elements with any name. So this selects every element which is a descendant of the root (i.e. all the elements in the document).

The next part, `/id(@*)`, takes that sequence of elements and evaluates the function call `id(@*)` for each one. This is the complicated part:

If the element has at least one attribute, then the expression `@*` will produce a sequence of attributes which will passed to the `id()` function, which will return a sequence of elements in the document whose ID matches one of the tokens in the attribute values in the sequence (NB an attribute like `link="x y z"` will contribute 3 tokens 'x', 'y', and 'z'). So if your document has an element like `<a reference1="b" reference2="c d"/>`, then the `id()` function will return elements which have the ID property of `b` or `c` or `d`, e.g. `<c xml:id='c'/>` would be returned if it were in the document.

If the element has *no* attributes, then the expression `@*` returns an empty sequence, and I think in that case the `id()` function will use the value of the context node instead. So an element like `<b>c</b` will pass 'c' to the `id()` function, unlike an element like `<b ref="foo">c</b>`, which will pass 'foo'.

So essentially this second step returns elements which have an ID referred to by *any* attribute of *any* element in the document.

The final step `/*` of the path would simply return the child elements of the elements returned from that second step.

For example, with this document:

```xml
<test>
  <a xml:id="a">
    <b/>
  </a>
  <c xml:id="c">
    <d/>
  </c>
  <e xml:id="e">
    <f/>
  </e>
  <g ref="a" ref2="c"/>
  <h>e</h>
</test>
```

... evaluating `//*/id(@*)/*` should return this result:

```
<b/>
<d/>
<f/>
```

Comment: In case it's not obvious from the above, it's a very weird expression that probably has no real useful purpose except as a puzzle. It may well just be a mistake. Do you have the XML that it's supposed to work with? It may make more sense when you read it alongside the XML it's intended to query.